# LM3478 48V boost converter

Tags: boost, converter

[image: simulation][LM3478 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3478.pdf)

[image]

This circuit was designed with the help of Ti webench, I have checked all the connections, everything checks out. When i connect a 24V 2.2A Dc supply the supply voltage drops to 3V but nothing gets heated up. If the circuit is connected to the supply and then i turn on the power the power supply voltage drops to 3v and output is less than 3V. While the power supply is ON if i connect the converter the output voltage is 48V.
Can someone shed some light on this mystery?

Comment: *When i connect a 24V 2.2A Dc supply* yet in the report it says: VinMax = 20 V, yet you connect 24 V. Why? Did you follow the PCB layout example from the datasheet of the LM3478? Did you use the exact components that are specified?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie this is a TI design tool, so it's relatively certain that the circuit as shown is as intended by TI.

Comment: I have used the exact components, 24V is the maximum the supply can output i have turned it down to 20V

Comment: "supply voltage drops to 3V" which one is your "supply voltage": Vin or Vout?

Comment: Vin , i have used a Mean well DC supply which is connected to Vin.

Comment: Do you have any load on the output of the converter?

Comment: What transistor did you actually use for M1? I'm wondering whether it might be damaged (shorted). What is the voltage across Rsense?

Comment: @VladimirCravero no load is connected

Comment: @DaveTweed AO4260S ,its rated for more than the application and its not shorted , If it was it wouldn't work at all

Comment: i have attached simulation too, it seems Brian Drummond's hunch was right. within the first 4ms of the simulation the current drawn from the supply is huge,it ranges from 24 to 2.5A after 4ms it settles down. I think the supply's protective mechanism is preventing that so the voltage drops. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, but...

You probably have to delay its startup.

Why?

If the input supply is initially at less than the full 24V, a boost converter will attempt to generate the full output voltage by drawing excessive current from it.  ( P = I * V ... lower V implies higher I for the rated power) That will trigger whatever protection the input supply has, preventing it increasing its output voltage, and (depending on the supply circuitry, holding it in "foldback" at very low voltage.

With the power supply running first, it already supplies 24V when the boost converter starts, removing the need for excessive current at low voltage. The same is likely true if COUT is already charged close to rated voltage.

Delay the startup, and the boost converter should stay within the supply's rated current. (There will be some surge as it charges Cout but your results suggest the PSU can cope with that.)

How?

Look for "inhibit" or "power down" or "standby" hints in the datasheet. You didn't link it so I'll leave that as an exercise. I can't see an "inhibit" pin in your schematic but there are sometimes documented ways to use the "FB" or "comp" or "Isense" pins for the purpose..

Then apply appropriate signals to those pins for an appropriate time after startup. Test thoroughly; switching off and back on immediately can catch out some of these strategies.

Comment: Thanks i'll work on your hint. If the supply is running before the boost converter is connected and if i connect it then it instantly turns ON . I get 48V at output of the converter without any delay.can you explain this behavior with regards to your explanation.

Comment: one more thing , If the converter is switched back ON within few seconds when its working properly the converter outputs 48V , if i turned off the supply and the output voltage of the capacitor drops below 44V and then i turn ON it does'nt work.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who chipped in their opinion. As Brian Drummond and user287001 pointed out,the current demand placed by the boost converter has turned ON the protection circuit in the input supply hence the supply drops the voltage so as to stop the inrush current even though it is for a few msec.I connected a 12.8V ,12Ah lithium battery it turns on without any delay owing to the batteries current supplying capability.

Comment: i want to know why the dc input supply works when i connect the converter after powering the dc input supply first

Comment: I rushed through your answer, you have answered most of my question.Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Boost converter draws high current peaks from the input and does it often if the output is low. Later it injects new current pulses to the output capacitor only when needed. A smart controller can in addition reduce the max current which is charged to the inductor if the output seems to stay acceptable and also reduce the current in startup. Datasheet seems to show that this IC has both, but they are not strong enough to keep your power supply happy, it sees overcurrent.

Something to try:

1) Add an inductor to the +voltage wire between the power supply and the boost circuit input, maybe 50uH is ok, insert about one ohm damping resistor in parallel with the inductor to avoid any resonance buildup.

2) Insert a circuit which in the startup fools the controller to think the undervoltage in the output is not that serious or the inductor current is higher than it actually is. The operation of the extra circuit should fade gradually.

Comment: I have a bit of clarity now. i want to know why the dc input supply works when i connect the converter after powering the dc input supply first.Maybe the supplies output capacitor is supplying the inrush current or the converters IC has problem with operating dc voltage. I read in the datasheet that below 7.5v it takes it from internal regulator above that it draws from Vin supply.If u can explain that would be awesome.

Comment: NTC Power Thermistor also can be used for limitting inrush current.

Comment: @JAGADISHK the regulator ic will enter to input undervoltage protection mode if something drops the input voltage so that the wanted input current isn't available. I suggested an inductor. It together with Cin filters input current pulses to lower peak level without severe voltage loss. I edited the answer to insert a damping resistor to prevent oscillations. I guess it's best to persuade the IC want less current at startup, if you want to use a strictly current limited power supply.